# Files with space in name

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have a variable called var that stores the list of files inside a directory. I loop through all the files and if I find a directory I output "Directory" to the screen. code below:

```
var=$(ls dir)

for file in $var; do
    if [ -d $dir/$file ]; then
        echo "Directory"
    fi
done
```

I have 2 questions:

1st- I am doing this inside a function and I want the $file variable to stay local so when my function ends I don't get access to it. How can I set that variable local? I cant do `for local file in $var;` and I cant declare $file before the loop.

2nd- My loop doesnt work when `$(ls dir)` contains a file that has a space inside the name. For example if `$dir` has 3 files, file1 file 2 and file3, `$var` would only hold file1 and file3 as real files but file 2 would not work because it would separate it into file and 2. How can I fix the problem of the files that have space in their names?

Comment: for the space, put double quotes around 
`"$file"`. for more complex situations you might have to use `$"$file"`.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work because I am already getting the space from $(ls dir), so when I initialize my variable file I am already taking the space into consideration.

Comment: Try `ls -Q dir`. this will put quotes around each file name. This issue is part of why it is recommended that people avoid parsing `ls` output, and instead use `find`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For making $file local: you can use `local file` before assigning to it.

For files with spaces: [don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use a wildcard, and use double-quotes around variable references:

```
local file
for file in "$dir"/*; do  # Note that $file will contain $dir as well as the filename
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then
        echo "Directory: $file"
    fi
done
```

If you want to store the file names before starting the loop, use an array instead of a plain variable:

```
local -a filelist
filelist=("$dir"/*)
local file
for file in "${filelist[@]}"; do
    ...
```

See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for more complex examples and more tricks.